# Getting two different values from a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, return

I am trying to create a function in **python** that splits a string in to two strings, where the first one have all the lower case letters + some other special characters and the second one having all the upper case letters + special characters.

**The point is to be able to type:**

```
>>> first_message,second_message=string_split("SomEChaRacTers")
>>> print(first_message, second_message)
```

to get the result printed.

**This is what i have right now:**

```
def string_split(string):
    first_message_signs = "_."
    second_message_signs = " |"
    one = ""
    two = ""
    if len(string) == 0:
        return string
    
    if string[0].islower() or string[0] in first_message_signs:
        one += string[0] + string_split(string[1:])
        return one
    
    elif string[0].isupper() or string[0] in second_message_signs:
        two += string[0] + string_split(string[1:])
        return two
    else:
        return string_split(string[1:])
```

**I am getting this error when making the first call in the prompt:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

When i try with only message_one i get all the characters in one string.

What should i do?

Comment: All of your `return` statements need to return 2 values instead of just 1.

Comment: I suggest calling your values `upper` and `lower` instead of `one` and `two` so you can manage them better. This might also make it more obvious what your `return` should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line

```
first_message,second_message=string_split("SomEChaRacTers")
```

expects `string_split` to return two values.  However, your function only ever returns one.

What you want is

```
def string_split(string):
    first_message_signs = "_."
    second_message_signs = " |"
    one = ""
    two = ""
    if len(string) == 0:
        return one, two
    
    if string[0].islower() or string[0] in first_message_signs:
        one += string[0]
    elif string[0].isupper() or string[0] in second_message_signs:
        two += string[0]

    ret1, ret2 = string_split(string[1:])
    one += ret1
    two += ret2

    return one, two
```

On a side note, there's no compelling reason for `string_split` to be recursive.  Try this:

```
def string_split(string):
    first_message_signs = "_."
    second_message_signs = " |"

    one = ''.join(c for c in string if c.islower() or c in first_message_signs)
    two = ''.join(c for c in string if c.isupper() or c in second_message_signs)

    return one, two
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, when i try the recursive solution i get this as an error:                                              
              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  line 124, in string_split
  line 124, in string_split
  line 124, in string_split
  [Previous line repeated 6 more times]
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: What's line 124?

Comment: ret1, ret2 = string_split(string[1:])

Comment: Are you sure you typed it in correctly?  I just ran my code and I got `'omhaacers'` for `first_message` and `'SECRT'` for `second_message`.

Comment: I have tried several times but am getting the same error every time :( I even copied the code from your answer

Comment: It seems that there was a problem with the top return statement in my code but i managed to solve it now :) thank you